# The LTSM does not predict Apple Stock Close column well

Tags: neural-network, lstm, prediction

I am using LSTM (Long Short Term Memory) to predict the Apple Stock Closing prices using the 3 previous days. My problem is that the model underestimate closing prices. The photo of the final result is given at the end of this passage.

First of all, I have a very highly left skewed data set of Apple stocks as can be seen from the photo below. I used a LSTM model to predict the closing prices using 3 previous days and a batch size of 10.

[image]

```
rec_obj <- recipe(Close ~ .,aapl) %>%
    step_sqrt(Close) %>%
    step_center(Close) %>%
    step_scale(Close) %>%
    prep()


aapl_normalized <- bake(rec_obj, aapl) #10372 observations. 

#keep centers for denormalization later
center_history <- rec_obj$steps[[2]]$means["Close"]
center_history
scale_history  <- rec_obj$steps[[3]]$sds["Close"]
scale_history
c("center" = center_history, "scale" = scale_history)
```

### Train validation and test datasets

```
aapl_trn <- aapl_normalized[1:8500,] 
aapl_val <- aapl_normalized[8501:9401,] #900
aapl_test <- aapl_normalized[9402:10372 ,] #970
```

### Reshaping the Data

```
n_inputs <- 3 #number of inputs in the RNN e.g. 1st it. use first 10 days to predict the 11th
n_predictions <- 1
batch_size <- 10 #number of batches that you give. large the model is faster -- parmeter
```

##### Functions

```
build_windowed_matrix <- function(data, timesteps) { #tranforms data into the  windows of 4+1) if you have 14K rows this produce a matric of 14K x 5
  t(sapply(1:(length(data) - timesteps + 1), function(x) 
    data[x:(x + timesteps - 1)]))
}

reshape_3D <- function(df){ #to do it 14kx5x1 since this is required by keras. If it was multivariate (n) it should be  14kx5xn!!!
  dim(df) <- c(dim(df)[1], dim(df)[2], 1)
  df
}

get_x <- function(mtx, n_inputs, batch_size){#for each row gets the the x's (4 in number) 
  mtx <- mtx[, 1:n_inputs]
  mtx <- mtx[1:(nrow(mtx) %/% batch_size * batch_size), ]
  reshape_3D(mtx)
}

get_y <- function(mtx, n_inputs, n_predictions, batch_size) {#for each row gets the the y (5th element) + put them in 3D
  mtx <- mtx[, (n_inputs+1):(n_inputs+n_predictions), drop=FALSE]
  mtx <- mtx[1:(nrow(mtx) %/% batch_size * batch_size), , drop=FALSE]
  if(n_predictions==1){
    dim(mtx) <- c(length(mtx)[1], 1)
  }
  reshape_3D(mtx)
}
```

##### Extract 'Close' Values

Extract close values and disregard dates

```
trn <- aapl_trn %>% select(Close) %>% pull() #into  vector
val <- aapl_val %>% select(Close) %>% pull()
test <- aapl_test %>% select(Close) %>% pull()
```

##### Build matrices

actually using the functions that I defined aboved

```
trn_mtx <- build_windowed_matrix(trn, n_inputs + n_predictions)
val_mtx <- build_windowed_matrix(val, n_inputs + n_predictions)
test_mtx <- build_windowed_matrix(test, n_inputs + n_predictions)

X_train <- get_x(trn_mtx, n_inputs, batch_size) #X_train_close
Y_train <- get_y(trn_mtx, n_inputs, n_predictions, batch_size)
X_val <- get_x(val_mtx, n_inputs, batch_size)
Y_val <- get_y(val_mtx, n_inputs, n_predictions, batch_size)
X_test <- get_x(test_mtx, n_inputs, batch_size)
Y_test <- get_y(test_mtx, n_inputs, n_predictions, batch_size) #Y_test is the actual closing value in the test set. 
head(X_test)
head(Y_test)
```

I am using the LSTM model below:

1.) Build first model (use only close)

````
model <- keras_model_sequential()

model %>%
  layer_lstm(  #lstm with 32 units in each cell
    units = 32,
    batch_input_shape = c(batch_size, n_inputs, 1) #1 feature is included
  )

 layer_lstm(  #lstm with 32 units in each cell
    units = 16,
    batch_input_shape = c(batch_size, n_inputs, 1)
  )
 
model %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 1)

model %>%
  compile(
    loss = 'mean_squared_error',
    optimizer = 'sgd',
    metrics = list("mean_squared_error")
  ) '''

```{r}
callbacks <- list(#stop criterion depends on if the network is not learning any more...stop the model from training after 5 epochs if there is no learning
  callback_early_stopping(patience = 5)
)
````

```
history <- model %>% fit(
  x = X_train,
  y = Y_train,
  validation_data = list(X_val, Y_val),
  batch_size = batch_size,
  epochs = 100,
  callbacks = callbacks
)
```

#### Predictions using one feature

```
pred_test <- model %>%
  predict(X_test, batch_size = batch_size) 

# de-normalize to original scale
pred_test <- (pred_test * scale_history + center_history) ^2 #denormalization
mse_test <- (pred_test - Y_test[,,1]) ^2  #Y_test is the actual closing value in the test set.
```

#### Plot predictions vs actual

```
ggplot(aapl[(9402 + n_inputs):(9401 + n_inputs + dim(pred_test)[1]),], aes(x = Date, y = Close, group = 1)) + geom_line() +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = levels(aapl$Date)[floor(seq(1, nlevels(aapl$Date),length.out = 5))]) +
  geom_line(aes(y = pred_test), color = "blue") +
  labs(x = "Date", y = "Close Value", title = "Apple Stock")
```

[image]

As you see from the graph, my model does seem to underestimate the values. How can I fix this? I tried hyperparameter tuning but it didn't work. Is it because my data was super left skewed? How do I go about this?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest first to smooth the data with moving average or some technique. Furthermore, you have 16 hidden sizes in the second layer. I would suggest increasing both layers 64, with the later layer optional in the construction of the model.

Comment: Thank you very much. I can log the data. How should I delog it if it is already scaled and centered by the recipe function? pred_test <- model %>% predict(X_test, batch_size = batch_size) # de-normalize to original scale pred_test <- (pred_test * scale_history + center_history) ^10 #denormalization  Will this denormalisation work?

Answer (score 0):

I have some questions and some suggestions.

Questions first :

- did you set the nonlinear layer between the layers?
- what's you learning parameters? such as loss function

suggestion:

- I think you have to normalize the close price data for each batch of data.

if you answer my questions, i can get a better guidance.